# On start up my Activity screen position cuts off half my UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and am having an issue with my first app's UI. When a particular activity starts up, the screen position is initially scrolled so that it cuts off the top couple view items in my UI. The issue appears to be with the ExpandableListView and my implementation of it. The Activity wants to place it at the top of the screen initially. How do i prevent this scrolling from happening so that a user will see the top of my activity when they start it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys!

Screenshots: Initial: http://imgur.com/FMba5 Desired: http://imgur.com/oEx1N

Here is the main Layout of the Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_league_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="League Settings"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:focusable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_players_prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/new_league_title"
        android:text="@string/num_players_prompt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/num_players_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/num_players_prompt"
        android:prompt="@string/num_players_prompt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roster_size_prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/roster_size_prompt"
        android:layout_below="@id/num_players_spinner"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/roster_size_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/roster_size_prompt" 
        android:prompt="@string/roster_size_prompt" />

     <ExpandableListView
         android:id="@+id/scoring_settings_list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="1000dp"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:layout_below="@+id/roster_size_spinner" />

</RelativeLayout>    

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the Layout I use for the children of the ExpandedListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<EditText
   android:id="@+id/settingEditText"
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   android:maxLength="3"
   android:paddingLeft="6dp"
   android:paddingRight="6dp"
   android:text="6.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settingLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Java code for the activity

```
public class NewLeagueActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_league);
    setUpUI();

}

public void setUpUI(){

    //Sets up the # of players in league spinner
    Spinner numPlayersSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.num_players_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.num_players, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    numPlayersSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    numPlayersSpinner.setSelection(2);

    //Sets up the max roster size spinner
    Spinner rosterSizeSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.roster_size_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.roster_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    rosterSizeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
    rosterSizeSpinner.setSelection(2);

    //Sets up the expandable listview for Passing settings
    ExpandableListView passScoring = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.scoring_settings_list);
    passScoring.setAdapter(new EditScoringAdapter());

}

public class EditScoringAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private String[] groups = { "Score Settings for Passing", "Score Settings for Rushing",
            "Score Settings for Receiving", "Score Settings for Kicking", "Score Settings for Defense", "Score Settings for Special Teams" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "Points per Passing Touchdown", "Passing Yards per Point", "Points per Interception Thrown" },
            { "Points per Rushing Touchdown", "Rushing Yards per Point", "Points per Fumble" },
            { "Points per Receiving Touchdown", "Receiving Yards per Point", "Points per Reception" },
            { "Points per PAT", "Points per Field Goal (0-39 yds)", "Points per Field Goal (40-49 yds)", "Points per Field Goal (50+ yds)" },
            { "Points per Interception", "Points per Fumble Recovery", "Points per Sack", "Points per Safety", "Points per Defensive Touchdown",
                "Points per Blocked Kick", "Points for Allowing 0 Points", "Points for Allowing 1-6 Points",
                "Points for Allowing 7-13 Points", "Points for Allowing 14-17 Points", "Points for Allowing 18-21 Points",
                "Points for Allowing 22-27 Points", "Points for Allowing 35-45 Points", "Points for Allowing 46+ Points"},
            {}
    };

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = NewLeagueActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View editTextView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.labeled_edit_text, null);
        ((TextView)editTextView.findViewById(R.id.settingLabel)).setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        return editTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        //Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(NewLeagueActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(75, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think that's because you're nesting a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've un-nested them and it is working as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ScrollView`. It's supposedly not a good practice to nest `ListView` in a `ScrollView` and/or vice versa. See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2d1a4b8063b2d8f7?pli=1) for more details.